# I can't figure out why this transaction simulation is failing

Tags: spl-token, pda, anchor-test

I'm working on a simple proof of concept guessing game like Clue, written in Anchor Lang, and I'm having trouble getting one of my transactions to work correctly.

Here is the code in question:

```
// lib.rs
...
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(murderer: u8, weapon: u8, room: u8)]
pub struct Guess<'info> {
    #[account(seeds = [b"clue"], bump)]
    game: Account<'info, Game>, // initialized in previous instruction

    #[account(mut)]
    user: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    user_usdc_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    team_usdc_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(
        seeds = [usdc_mint.key().as_ref()], 
        bump, 
        token::mint = usdc_mint, 
        token::authority = game
    )]
    prize_pool: Account<'info, TokenAccount>, // this is a PDA and a TokenAccount, the goal is that the program holds a prize pool until someone guesses correctly.

    #[account(mut)]
    usdc_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
...
```

This is how I'm setting up the test:

```
// clue.ts
...
const user = Keypair.generate();
const team = Keypair.generate();

await airdrop(user.publicKey, connection);
await airdrop(team.publicKey, connection);

await mintTo(connection, user, usdcMint, user.publicKey, mintAuthority, 20);
await mintTo(connection, team, usdcMint, team.publicKey, mintAuthority, 20);

const userUsdcAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  user,
  usdcMint,
  user.publicKey
);
const teamUsdcAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  team,
  usdcMint,
  team.publicKey
);

try {
  await connection.confirmTransaction(
    await program.methods
      .guess(1, 0, 0)
      .accounts({
        game,
        user: user.publicKey,
        userUsdcAccount: userUsdcAccount.address,
        teamUsdcAccount: teamUsdcAccount.address,
        prizePool,
        usdcMint,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .signers([user])
      .rpc(),
    "confirmed"
  );

  const gameAccount = (await program.account.game.all())[0].account;
  console.log("gameAccount:", gameAccount);
  console.log(await getAccount(connection, prizePool));
  assert.isTrue(true);
} catch (e) {
  assert.fail(e);
}
...
```

The error I'm getting is: **Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction**

I'm not sure what's going on here. I'm initializing the **game** and **prize_pool** accounts earlier in the same test. I'm initializing them like this:

```
// clue.ts
...
let authority: Keypair;
let game: PublicKey;
let bump: number;
let usdcMint: PublicKey;
let prizePool: PublicKey;
const mintAuthority = Keypair.generate();

before(async () => {
  authority = (provider.wallet as NodeWallet).payer;

  const gPDA = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("clue")],
    program.programId
  );
  game = gPDA[0];
  bump = gPDA[1];

  usdcMint = await createMint(
    connection,
    authority,
    mintAuthority.publicKey,
    mintAuthority.publicKey,
    9
  );

  const pPool = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [usdcMint.toBuffer()],
    program.programId
  );
  prizePool = pPool[0];
  console.log(`Prize Pool PubKey: ${prizePool.toString()}`);
});
...
```

My suspicion is that it is the PDA/TokenAccount **prize_pool**, but I'm unsure. The goal of the **prize_pool** is that it should be a TokenAccount owned by the program that can send and receive USDC.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may be because the `game` and `prize_pool` token account haven't been created yet.

The code you've provided where you mention initializing the `game` and `prizePool` accounts only derives the PDAs. (`findProgramAddressSync` only derives the PDA, but does not initialize any accounts).

```
  const gPDA = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("clue")],
    program.programId
  );

  const pPool = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [usdcMint.toBuffer()],
    program.programId
  );
```

Is there another instruction in your program that initializes the `game` account and the `prize_pool` token account?

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll make some updates and report back 